# Adding 20 works but subtracting 20 doesn't - how can I fix my Javascript code for an Ecommerce website?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an Ecommerce website. When you click/check a varietion it adds 20 on the total price 100. But when you uncheck the varietion it doesn't minus on the total price. Please help me I've been trying this for months and it just won't work.

Here's my code:

```html
<div id="total">500</div>
    
    <input onclick="addTwenty()" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">R20</input>

    <script>

        let total = document.getElementById("total");
        let twenty = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

        function addTwenty(){
            total = 500;
            twenty = 20;
            if (twenty.checked = true){
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + twenty;
            } else{
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total - twenty;
            }
        }
        
    </script>
```

I used If statements. When true, it adds value of 20 on 500, which is 520. But when unchecked it doesn't minus 20. I want it to minus the same value it added when it's now unchecked.

Comment: You just set `twenty` to `20`, the `twenty.checked` will no longer check the input element.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Cause and explanation are given below.

#### when checked add 20, when unchecked it returns back to 500

```js
    const twenty_check_box = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

    function addTwenty() {
        total = 500;
        twenty = 20;
        if (twenty_check_box.checked == true) {
            total += twenty;
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
        } else {
           total -= twenty;
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
        }
    }
```

#### Cause

on `line 8` you set twenty as the checkbox -> `let twenty = document.getElementById("checkbox1");`

But on `line 12`, you set `twenty = 20;` so now the variable twenty does not contain the element, instead, it now has integer 20.

Again, on `line 13`, in condition, you used `(twenty.checked = true)`... But to make it clear to you, `=` is used to assign value and `==` is used to check/compare value, so you need to use `==` here as `(twenty.checked == true)`

### Solution Explanation

so, we take the checkbox as `twenty_check_box` instead of `twenty` and set it to constant. secondly, we check as `(twenty_check_box.checked == true)`. and also update the total variable as `total += twenty` meaning `total = total + twenty` and show it, so now total is **520**

then if unchecked, it subtracts 20 from `total` so now `total` is **500** again.

Hope it solves the issue...

Answer (score 1):

you should assign values to innerHTML not variables here.

```html
<div id="total">500</div>

<input onclick="addTwenty()" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">R20</input>

<script>
  let totalElement = document.getElementById("total");
  let twentyElement = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

  // ...

  function addTwenty() {
    let total = parseInt(totalElement.innerHTML);
    let twenty = 20;

    if (twentyElement.checked === true) {
      totalElement.innerHTML = total + twenty;
    } else {
      totalElement.innerHTML = total - twenty;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If 500 symbolizes a price parseInt() would be suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator, not the equality check operator. You should use `===` instead of `=`, or better yet, since this is a Boolean, just omit it altogether:

```js
if (twenty.checked) {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + twenty;
} else{
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total - twenty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change twenty variable name inside addTwenty function to amount, then it will work. And change your equal comparison from = to === .

```
    let twenty = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

    function addTwenty(){
        total = 500;
        amount = 20;
        if (twenty.checked === true){
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + amount;
        } else{
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total - amount;
        }
    }
    
   twenty.addEventListener("click", function(){
   addTwenty();
   });
```